# Heap heap space error when parallelizing experiments

Tags: java, parallel-processing, heap-memory, weka

I have a program designed to run lots of weka experiments in parallel.
For this I build a program which loads a protobuf experiment description from files. Those are then wrapped in a Runnable which gets executed by an ExecutorService.

```
public static Runnable runExperiment(
      ExperimentDescription experimentDescription) throws Exception {
    class RunnableExperiment implements Runnable {
      ExperimentDescription experimentDescription;
      public RunnableExperiment(
          ExperimentDescription experimentDescription) {
        this.experimentDescription = experimentDescription;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Experiment experiment = Experiment.build(experimentDescription);
          experiment.trainClassifier();
          experiment.evaluate();
          experiment=null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    RunnableExperiment experiment = new RunnableExperiment(
          experimentDescription);
    return experiment;  
  }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    for (ExperimentDescription experimentDescription : experimentsInFile) {
        executor.execute(runExperiment(experimentDescription));
     }
}
```

The experiments them self basically contain only their dataset which is max 100mb big, which they read from the file specified in the experiment description.
I work on a strong machine with 15 cores and 80G ram, from which i use 50 with -Xmx50000m.
Yet I get the typical Heap space errors, and I can not find my error.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging steps? In other words, trying thread pools other than newFixedThreadPool. Maybe newSingleThreadExecutor? Also you could step through a debugger to see the execution path on the for-loop in main(). It's possible the experimentsInFile are all being read and queued to the executor with no constraints on the experimentsInFile being read. In other words, check how executor.execute(runExperiment(experimentDescription)) is controlled. The program flow may execute the line, resulting in the memory use of the experimentDescription being loaded.

Comment: It's a Heap error so what does `Experiment.build` do?  Are you popping there?  What about your `for` loop? Is `experimentDescription` correct?  If not you'd be creating a ton of `RunnableExperiment`s

Comment: It would help if you could add the exact error message that you are seeing.